# Kubernetes master on GCE not display node on AWS EC2

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I created master node on GCE using this commands:

```
gcloud compute instances create master --machine-type g1-small --zone europe-west1-d
gcloud compute addresses create myexternalip --region europe-west1
gcloud compute target-pools create kubernetes --region europe-west1
gcloud compute target-pools add-instances kubernetes --instances master --instances-zone europe-west1-d
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create kubernetes-forward --address myexternalip --region europe-west1 --ports 1-65535 --target-pool kubernetes
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe kubernetes-forward
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

and opened all firewalls.

After it i created aws ec2 instance, opened firewalls and using:

`kubeadm join --token 55d287.b540e254a280f853 ip:6443 --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification`

to connecting instance to cluster.

**But in the master node it is not displayed**

Docker version: 17.12

Kubernetes version: 1.9.3

**UPD:**

Output from node on aws ec2

**systemctl status kubelet.service:**

```
kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-02-24 20:23:53 UTC; 23s ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 30678 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 5
   Memory: 13.4M
      CPU: 125ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─30678 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests -

Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.420375   30678 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.420764   30678 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.420944   30678 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: W0224 20:23:53.425410   30678 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.444969   30678 server.go:182] Version: v1.9.3
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.445274   30678 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:23:53 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30678]: I0224 20:23:53.445565   30678 plugins.go:101] No cloud provider specified.
```

**journalctl -u kubelet:**

```
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopping kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent...
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30243]: I0224 20:15:12.819249   30243 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30243]: I0224 20:15:12.821054   30243 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30243]: I0224 20:15:12.821243   30243 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30243]: error: unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 24 20:15:12 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30304]: I0224 20:15:23.186834   30304 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30304]: I0224 20:15:23.187255   30304 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30304]: I0224 20:15:23.187451   30304 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30304]: error: unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 24 20:15:23 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30311]: I0224 20:15:33.422948   30311 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30311]: I0224 20:15:33.423349   30311 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30311]: I0224 20:15:33.423525   30311 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30311]: error: unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 24 20:15:33 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 24 20:15:43 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 24 20:15:43 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:43 ip-172-31-0-250 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 24 20:15:43 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30319]: I0224 20:15:43.671742   30319 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
Feb 24 20:15:43 ip-172-31-0-250 kubelet[30319]: I0224 20:15:43.672195   30319 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
```

**UPD:**

Error is on aws ec2 instance side, but i can't find what is wrong.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Should initialize kubeadm with this flag `--apiserver-advertise-address`

Comment: are you sure the node joined the cluster? try having a look at the `kubelet` process logs in the node machine.

Comment: Looks like kubelet is crashing because it can't find the certificates to connect to the master: `error: unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create load balancer you need to type this command for show you external load balancer ip address

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe kubernetes-forward
```

And the initialize cluster with this flag

```
--apiserver-advertise-address=external_load_balancer_ip
```

So your kubeadm command looks like this

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=external_load_balancer_ip
```